# Write n in terms of multiplication of numbers from A=[1,...,n] such that the total cost of chosen number is maximum

Tags: dynamic-programming

We want to write n in terms of multiplication of numbers from A = [1,...,n] such that the total cost is maximum. The cost of choosing the ith number is `cost[i]`. Note that `cost[1] = 0` and we can choose 1 number **multiple times**.

For example :

```
n = 12
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
cost = [0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20]
12 = 1*2*2*3(Cost = 0+1+1+2 = 4)
.
.
.
12 = 1*12(Cost = 0 + 20)
So the maximum of total cost is 20.
```

My attempt:

I tried to form a table from factors of n.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $i = 2, \dots, n$ define $C[i]$ as the maximum cost that can be attained if the product of the selected factors must be $i$ and $c_i$ as the cost of selecting $i$.

Given $i$, let $P_i$ be the multiset of prime factors of $i$ (with multiplicity) and notice that $|P_i|=O(\log n)$. You have:

$$
C[i] = \max \left\{ c_i, \max_{\substack{S \subset P_i \\ |S| \le |P_i|/2}}  \left( C\left[\prod_{s \in S} s\right]  + C\left[\prod_{s \in P \setminus S} s\right] \right) \right\}.
$$

This immediately gives you a polynomial-time dynamic programming algorithm.